# Calling stored procedure from MS Access results in error 3146

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

When I call a SQL Server stored procedure from MS Access front-end using the code shown below, it stops running and throws the runtime error "3146".

This stored procedure is working correctly in SQL Server, but when I run from MS Access, it is working at first, but suddenly stops and throws that runtime error "3146".

For more clearance this stored procedure is for inserting records in an empty table when I do from MS Access it should insert 1000 records, but it inserts 970 records and then stops.

My stored procedure had a select query for inserting records, now I have changed this easy select query to a union query, since I have changed this in the design of stored procedure it is working fine in SQL Server

```
Public Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")

    qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[ASBUILT_LIST]").Connect
    qdef.SQL = "EXEC Update_Asbuilt2"
    qdef.ReturnsRecords = False  ''avoid 3065 error
    qdef.Execute
    qdef.Close

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: As it runs but not to the end I assume a permission problem. On error 3146 loop through the Errors Collection with `For I = 0 To Errors.Count-1 Debug.Print Errors(I) Next I `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it runs, but not until the end, then it is probably not a permission problem, but a **timeout** problem

you can do a :

```vb
debug.print qdef.ODBCTimeout
```

to know what your current Timeout value is.

Then just increase it with enough seconds to complete the stored procedure :

```vb
Public Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")

    qdef.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[ASBUILT_LIST]").Connect
    ' --------------- Define TimeOut in Seconds ----------------
    qdef.ODBCTimeout = 2000 
    ' ----------------------------------------------------------        
    qdef.SQL = "EXEC Update_Asbuilt2"
    qdef.ReturnsRecords = False  ''avoid 3065 error
    qdef.Execute
    qdef.Close

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks my qdef.ODBCTimeout was 60, i do not know how it was 60, and i had not changed it's  default value before.

Comment: [Default is 60 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/odbctimeout-property) ;-)