# Run-Time Error 3146 - VBA Access Execute Stored Procedure - Cursor state(#0)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting an error code (3146: ODBC-call failed - Invalid cursor state (#0) on my local machine using Microsoft Access 365, but it works in our remote desktop environment using 2016 Access Professional Plus.

After [reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233841/calling-stored-procedure-from-ms-access-results-in-error-3146), I set my  ODBC timeout to 2000 in the query's property sheet, but still, get the same error and it only takes about 10 seconds to throw.

I also read that there were issues with the cursor state in an earlier version of Access 2016 and not sure if that is a problem with Office 365?

This subroutine has worked for years without any issues. It looks like it is tied to Office 365.

Any ideas?

The code errors on this line

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryImportGMSData" 'Creates tempTable with Weekly Import from GMS
```

Below is my subroutine

```
Sub GMSImport(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
Dim SqlStr As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()



'Builds query string for stored procedure maintained by SWDev from GMS to show Weekly Deals for report.
SqlStr = "EXEC  dbo.upRpt_WeeklyDealsReport @BeginDate = '" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ," & _
  " @EndDate = '" & Format(EndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ," & _
  " @RegionType_Short_List = 'CA~GC~MC~MW~SW~WE~NE' ," & _
  " @IncludeBulletDeals = 0 ," & _
  " @FormatType = 'spgexporttype'"

db.QueryDefs("ptqry_DataExport").sql = SqlStr 'sets the parameters for the stored procedure



DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryImportGMSData" 'Creates tempTable with Weekly Import from GMS

DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE temp_GMSImport ADD COLUMN Selected BIT" 'Add Selected Column to temp table
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE temp_GMSImport ADD COLUMN dvsValuationDef_ID INT" 'Adds Valuation Def Column to temp table
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE temp_GMSImport SET temp_GMSImport.Selected = -1;" 'Sets all Selected field to TRUE

DoCmd.SetWarnings True


End Sub
```

It errors out on this line:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryImportGMSData" 'Creates tempTable with Weekly Import from GMS
```

I am able to execute the stored procedure in SMSS with no issues:

```
"EXEC  dbo.upRpt_WeeklyDealsReport @BeginDate = '" & Format(StartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ," & _
  " @EndDate = '" & Format(EndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ," & _
  " @RegionType_Short_List = 'CA~GC~MC~MW~SW~WE~NE' ," & _
  " @IncludeBulletDeals = 0 ," & _
  " @FormatType = 'spgexporttype'"
```

When I test by 64 bit ODBC connection, it test successfully.

Update -more testing inside Access:

I was able to execute the T-SQL code inside Access without using VBA.

There are 3 queries involved in the sequence and the one that is not working is qryImportGMSData. It is a problem without using VBA, so that narrows it down a bit.

**qryImportGMSData**
Query: Make Table Query (Replicated)
***This one is causing the error***

```
SELECT *   INTO temp_GMSImport
FROM qryImportTransform;
```

**qryImportTransform**
Query: Select Query (Replicated) ***Works***

```
SELECT *
FROM ptqry_DataExport;
```

**Ptqry_DataExport**
SQL Pass-Through Query (Replicated) ***Works***

```
EXEC  dbo.upRpt_WeeklyDealsReport @BeginDate = '2021-02-22' , @EndDate = '2021-02-28' , @RegionType_Short_List = 'CA~GC~MC~MW~SW~WE~NE' , @IncludeBulletDeals = 0 , @FormatType = 'spgexporttype'
```

Comment: That error seems to suggest that some "cursor" processing in the store proc is not returning any rows - and thus some code in the store proc is failing. I don't think this is a a access issue. If you find a case in which this errors out? I would debug.print the store proc call, fire up SSMS and paste in the SAME command and see what SSMS spits out when you try to run that store proc. It also possible that you messed with the connection string that the PT query uses as say opposed to the linked table(s) connection strings (they should be the same).  Not clear if this is access or the store proc

Comment: Hi @AlbertD.Kallal,

I amended my question to address the issues you pointed out. Thanks

Comment: So, take what you typed into SSMS that you KNOW works. Open that PT query in design view paste that SAME t-sql from SSMS into that PT query. Save the query, and then double click on that query to see if it runs (that way, we can quick test the PT query and not have to use/run VBA code). If the t-sql works in SSMS, that pasted t-sql into the PT query should also work. So from nav pane launch/run the query and see if it works. Of course if the t-sql is to return data, then the query property sheet has returns records = yes, or = no if the SP does not return records. So test without VBA code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal ,

I was able to execute the T-SQL within Access. I did some more testing and figured out the issue lies with executing a make table query (qryImportGMSData) and amended my original question with the details. - thank you for al the help. It looks like we are narrowing it down to something specific.

Comment: See my answer below - give the "db" only object for all those queries and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we narrowed down that the PT query can work from Access.

We are likely dealing with two different connections - so there is a "wee bit" of asynchronous (threading) occurring here.

If not already, use the SAME connection object to run all 3 query.

So, use this:

```
db.Execute "qryImportGMSData",dbFailOnError
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE temp_GMSImport ADD COLUMN Selected BIT", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE temp_GMSImport ADD COLUMN dvsValuationDef_ID INT"
db.Execute "UPDATE temp_GMSImport SET temp_GMSImport.Selected = -1;",dbFailOnError
```

The other BIG advantage is above is faster, does NOT mess with the Access "UI" settings, and you don't have to change setwarnings.

And the above does NOT force access to try and use "transactions".

So, the problem is we using two different connections, you using "db", and then using the docmd which is a "separate" connection - and you can't control this much.

With two connection objects, it "almost" similar to two people running the two different parts of the code.

Give the above a try - stick to "one" connection object, so they can "behave" as a similar group of commands. And as noted, dumping docmd has several downsides, and is more attached to the Access "UI" options then it is to pure code.

Comment: I replaced the code above and get a similar code on this line
db.Execute "qryImportGMSData", dbFailOnError

Error code

Run-Time error '3146' ODBC -- call failed

I am not sure I understand this:
If not already, use the SAME connection object to run all 3 queries.

In the subroutine, I am using:
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I am using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 for my ODBC connection. I know there are several different drivers, but this one has worked in the past. Thanks